# Pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope:authorization failed

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, azure-devops, dockerfile

I am having issues with building a dotnet core image. When I run `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1`, this works but my dockerfile build is throwing the error 'failed to load cache key: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed' when I do a `docker build -t weatherapi -f Dockerfile .` Here's my dockerfile below

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1

WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj . 

RUN dotnet restore 

COPY . . 

RUN dotnet publish -c release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80

COPY --from=build /app/out .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet" "weather.dll"]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you've got a multi-stage Dockerfile but haven't named any stages. Specifically, the `COPY --from=build /app/out .` line references a stage named `build` that is not defined. This should resolve the issue (note the first line defines the `build` stage):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj . 

RUN dotnet restore 

COPY . . 

RUN dotnet publish -c release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80

COPY --from=build /app/out .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet" "weather.dll"]
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, this resolved the issue. Thanks for pointing that out.